# Haskell function to create an integer binary search tree given a list of integers

Tags: haskell

I am currently working on a Haskell function: `toList :: [Int] -> BTree` that will take in a list of integers (not necessarily ordered) and create a binary search out of these integers. For instance,

`toList [9,7,1,3]` 
should generate the following:

```
        3
      /   \
     1     7
    / \   / \
   E   E E   9
            / \
           E   E
```

Where E symbolizes an empty tree node.

Currently this is my BTree definition:

```
data BTree = Empty | Node Int BTree BTree
    deriving(Eq, Show)
```

This is my insert function:

```
insert :: BTree -> Int -> BTree
insert Empty a         = Node a Empty Empty
insert (Node a left right) b
    | b < a = Node a (insert left b) right
    | b > a = Node a left (insert right b)
```

And this is my attempt at the funtion as described above:

```
fromList :: [Int] -> BTree
fromList [] = Empty
fromList (x:xs) = foldr insert (Node x Empty Empty) xs
```

In this, I am trying to approach this by using the foldr function to call the insert function on a starting tree, then going through the list performing the insert function on the resultant tree; however I am getting two errors:

```
code.hs:27:25: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘BTree’ with ‘Int’
      Expected type: BTree -> BTree -> BTree
        Actual type: BTree -> Int -> BTree
    • In the first argument of ‘foldr’, namely ‘insert’
      In the expression: foldr insert (Node x Empty Empty) xs
      In an equation for ‘fromList’:
          fromList (x : xs) = foldr insert (Node x Empty Empty) xs
   |
27 | fromList (x:xs) = foldr insert (Node x Empty Empty) xs
   |                         ^^^^^^

code.hs:27:53: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘BTree’
      Expected type: [BTree]
        Actual type: [Int]
    • In the third argument of ‘foldr’, namely ‘xs’
      In the expression: foldr insert (Node x Empty Empty) xs
      In an equation for ‘fromList’:
          fromList (x : xs) = foldr insert (Node x Empty Empty) xs
   |
27 | fromList (x:xs) = foldr insert (Node x Empty Empty) xs
   |                                                     ^^
```

I am confused as to why this is, what I can do to fix this, and I would greatly appreciate any guidance. Thanks!

Comment: You have the arguments of `insert` flipped. See [the definition of `foldr`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.0/base-4.13.0.0/Prelude.html#v:foldr).

Comment: `fromList = foldr (flip insert) Empty` should work. There is no need to make a special case for the non-empty list. Alternatively, you could use `foldl` if you want to insert the elements form the left.